# Storing User Input across classes

Tags: c#

So I'm making a short text based game in C# and I'v encountered a problem.

A friend has helped me and told me that I need to use different classes and so far I've got one class which is the main menu and the character selection/class selection/difficulty selection.

Now when I go to write stuff in my second class (I want this class to contain the actual game) and it doesn't seem like variables such as name, class etc. are able to be carried over into this second class. I've tried searching google for it but haven't really found a good way to word it (Sorry if this is covered somewhere, if so please link).

Here is the pastebin link for the code (I tried to post it here but its too long to indent all lines): http://pastebin.com/6CJiZMjX

Thanks!

Comment: You could look at passing them as parameters into the new classes constructor as a simple mechanism.

Comment: you will need a class constructor to create the class. Then you can set values to it and access all of the properties you set the class. Try to look for quick tutorials on object-oriented programming.

Answer (score 1):

Your first issue is to do with **scope**.

You declare things like the difficulty and name in *local* scope, that is to say that they only exist within the method where you declare them.

Move them to a higher scope outside of the method.

```
namespace ConsoleApplication3
{
    class Initiation
    {
        public string name; // Here are your variables
        public int diff;    // Now they're accessible across the whole class
        ...                 

        void characterCreation()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Please enter your name: ");
            name = Console.ReadLine();
            Console.WriteLine("\nWelcome " + name + "!");
            ...
            ...
        }

        void difficultyMenu()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Please select a difficulty:\n1. Easy\n2. Medium\n3. Hard");
            diff = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
            ...
            ...
        }
    }
}
```

Your second issue is that your `Game` class needs to know this information. An easy way (but not the only one) is to create a constructor with some parameters that can be set for name, class and difficulty.

```
public class Game
{
    public string name { get; set; } // Read about auto-properties
    public int cclass { get; set; }
    public int diff { get; set; }

    // This is the constructor that assigns the values passed to this class
    public Game(string n, int c, int d)
    {
        name = n;
        cclass = c;
        diff = d;
    }

    // Example of gameStart that shows the chosen values
    public void gameStart()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("GAME STARTED:");
        Console.WriteLine(string.Format("Name: {0}, Class: {1}, Difficulty: {2}", name, cclass, diff));

    }
}
```

Now back in `Main` you need to instantiate and call `Game.gameStart()`.

```
public void Main(string[] args)
{
    ... // All your existing code is here
    ...

    // Create new instance of Game class and tell it the choices
    var game = new Game(name, cclass, diff);
    // Start the game
    game.gameStart();
}
```

Here's a Dot Net Fiddle.
https://dotnetfiddle.net/4qqh0y

Output:

> Main Menu
>     1. Play Game
>     2. Exit
>     **1**
>     Please enter your name:
>     **Equalsk**
>
> Welcome Equalsk!
>     Please select a class:
>     1. Warrior - Bonus damage with melee weapons, average health.
>     2. Ranger - Reduced health, bonus damage with ranged weapons.
>     3. Paladin - Low damage, bonus to health and armor.
>     **3**
>     You have chosen to be a Paladin, Equalsk!
>     Please select a difficulty:
>     1. Easy
>     2. Medium
>     3. Hard
>     **1**
>     You have selected easy difficulty!
>
> GAME STARTED:
>     Name: Equalsk, Class: 3, Difficulty: 1

Comment: The OP want's data to be available between classes not methods.

Comment: @DarrenYoung Amended with a proper (working) answer, thanks for setting me straight ;-)

Comment: Also, fix all your properties to be none-static. No point in that, since the class Game is not static.

Comment: @OriNachum Good point, my fault for copying and pasting things.

Comment: You've also got a typo here `class Initiation difficulty`

Comment: @DarrenYoung Cheers again. I'll show myself out now.

Comment: @Equalsk, wait! fix Initiation to have none static variables and classes! And you got your +1 from me :)

Comment: @OriNachum Sorry, they were a remnant of OPs code and I didn't think to remove them originally.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this.  Hope this helps.

```
//use this new class as a container to pass multiple items back to the calling procedure
public class Character {
     public string Name { get; set; }
     public int CharacterClass { get; set; }
     public int Diff { get; set; }
}

public class Initiation   //Pre-game stuff - Character name, class and game difficulty
{
    static Character characterCreation()  //changed return type to Character to return object of Class Character
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Please enter your name: ");
        string name = Console.ReadLine();
        Console.WriteLine("\nWelcome " + name + "!");
        Console.WriteLine("Please select a class:\n1. Warrior - Bonus damage with melee weapons, average health.\n2. Ranger - Reduced health, bonus damage with ranged weapons.\n3. Paladin - Low damage, bonus to health and armor.");
        int cclass = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
        switch (cclass)
        {
            case 1:
                Console.WriteLine("You have chosen to be a Warrior, " + name + "!");
                break;

            case 2:
                Console.WriteLine("You have chosen to be a Ranger, " + name + "!");
                break;

            case 3:
                Console.WriteLine("You have chosen to be a Paladin, " + name + "!");
                break;

            default:
                Console.WriteLine("Incorrect entry, please enter 1, 2 or 3!");
                break;
        }
        var character = new Character(); //build up the return Object
        character.Name = name;
        character.CharacterClass = cclass;
        character.Diff = Initiation.difficultyMenu();
        return character;
    }

    static int difficultyMenu()   //return type int so it returns the diff
    {
        do {
            Console.WriteLine("Please select a difficulty:\n1. Easy\n2. Medium\n3. Hard");
            int diff = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
            switch (diff)
            {
                case 1:
                    Console.WriteLine("You have selected easy difficulty!");
                    break;

                case 2:
                    Console.WriteLine("You have selected medium difficulty!");
                    break;

                case 3:
                    Console.WriteLine("You have selected hard difficulty!");
                    break;

                default:
                    Console.WriteLine("Incorrect entry! Please enter either 1, 2 or 3!");
                    break;
            }
        } while (diff<1 || diff >3)   // loop so program keeps asking until suitable input
        return diff; 
    }




    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Character character;
        Console.WriteLine("Main Menu");
        Console.WriteLine("1. Play Game");
        Console.WriteLine("2. Exit");

        int choice = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
        switch (choice)
        {
            case 1:
                character = characterCreation();  //created character is now returned
                Game game = new Game();
                game.gameStart(character);
                break;

            case 3:
                Environment.Exit(0);
                break;

            default:
                Console.WriteLine("Incorrect entry, please enter 1 or 2!");
                break;

        }
        Console.ReadLine();


    }
}

public class Game //Actual game
{
    static void gameStart(Character character)
    {


    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading;

namespace Game
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main (string[] args)
        {
            IAppModule module = new MainMenuModule ();

            while (true)
            {
                module = module.Run ();
                Console.Clear ();
            }
        }
    }

    public class Character
    {
        public string Name;
        public int Health, Armor, Damage;

        public static Character Warrior => new Character { Name = "Warrior", Health = 600, Armor = 20, Damage = 80  };
        public static Character Archer  => new Character { Name = "Archer",  Health = 250, Armor =  5, Damage = 35  };
        public static Character Mage    => new Character { Name = "Mage",    Health =  90, Armor =  0, Damage = 150 };
    }

    public interface IAppModule
    {
        IAppModule Run ();
    }

    public class ExitGameModule : IAppModule
    {
        public IAppModule Run ()
        {
            Console.WriteLine ("Thanks for playing!");
            Thread.Sleep (2000);
            Environment.Exit (0);

            return null;
        }
    }

    public class MainMenuModule : IAppModule
    {
        public IAppModule Run ()
        {
            var menu = new Menu ("Main menu:");

            menu.AddMenuEntry ("1", "start adventure", new SelectHeroModule ());
            menu.AddMenuEntry ("q", "exit game", new ExitGameModule ());

            return menu.Execute ();
        }
    }

    public class SelectHeroModule : IAppModule
    {
        public IAppModule Run ()
        {
            var mm = new Menu ("Select Hero");

            mm.AddMenuEntry ("1", "Paladin", new PlayModule (Character.Warrior));
            mm.AddMenuEntry ("2", "Archer",  new PlayModule (Character.Archer ));
            mm.AddMenuEntry ("3", "Mage",    new PlayModule (Character.Mage   ));

            mm.AddMenuEntry ("q", "Back to main menu", new MainMenuModule ());

            return mm.Execute ();
        }
    }

    public class PlayModule  : IAppModule
    {
        private Character character;

        public PlayModule  (Character character)
        {
            this.character = character;
        }

        public IAppModule Run ()
        {
            Console.WriteLine ("You are playing: " + character.Name);
            Console.WriteLine ("Health: " + character.Health);
            Console.WriteLine ("Armor: " + character.Armor);
            Console.WriteLine ("Damge: " + character.Damage);

            // game logic here

            Console.WriteLine ("\r\nPress any key to exit to menu.");
            Console.ReadKey ();

            return new MainMenuModule ();
        }
    }

    // helper class for building text menus

    public class Menu
    {
        private string title;
        private List<MenuItem> items = new List<MenuItem> ();

        public Menu (string title)
        {
            this.title = title;
        }

        public void AddMenuEntry (string cmd, string description, IAppModule module)
        {
            var item = new MenuItem
            {
                Command     = cmd,
                Description = description,
                Module      = module
            };

            items.Add (item);
        }

        public IAppModule Execute ()
        {
            Console.WriteLine ($"***** {title} *****\r\n");

            foreach (var item in items)
            {
                Console.WriteLine ($"{item.Command} - {item.Description}");
            }

            var cmd = GetCommand ();

            return items.First (x => x.Command == cmd).Module;
        }

        private string GetCommand ()
        {
            while (true)
            {
                Console.Write ("\r\nYour choice: ");

                string cmd = Console.ReadLine ();

                if (items.Any (x => x.Command == cmd)) return cmd;

                Console.WriteLine ("Invalid choice. Try again.");
            }
        }
    }

    public class MenuItem
    {
        public string Command, Description;
        public IAppModule Module;
    }
}
```